# Let's get critical: Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Genealogy & Family History Stack Exchange](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why would I export my raw DNA data?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3549/why-would-i-export-my-raw-dna-data)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [What DNA test does 23andMe perform?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3553/what-dna-test-does-23andme-perform)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Which passengers from the Komagata Maru were allowed to enter Canada?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3576/is-there-a-way-to-track-komagata-marus-travellers)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Source for Russian Army records for the WWI period](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/source-for-russian-army-records-for-the-wwi-period)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Glaziers in World War II](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/glaziers-in-world-war-ii)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Determining what records are available in a particular locale?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3625/how-can-i-determine-what-records-are-available-in-a-particular-locale)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Why wait more than 3 years to file the Petition for Naturalization?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3581/why-wait-more-than-3-years-to-file-the-petition-for-naturalization)

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Finding the Fatherless Feathers](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3608/finding-the-fatherless-feathers)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Birthplace of Phillip Smith](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3601/birthplace-of-phillip-smith)

  **Net Score: -6** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 6)
- [How can I assess the statistical probability that an individual is the one I seek?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/3580/how-can-i-assess-the-statistical-probability-that-an-individual-is-the-one-i-see)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)